# Successful payment with PayPal but no activity on buyers account

Tags: php, rest, paypal

I am developing an application which needs an access to PayPal. I use the php-rest-paypal sdk. In my Sandbox account you can see green-checked api calls and after I complete the payment with the sandbox account not activity is shown in my "buyers" or "facilitator"-account?

I tried to Google it but it seems like I am the only one who has this issue.

Here is my code:

```
$apiContext = new ApiContext(
    new OAuthTokenCredential(
        $this->clientID,
        $this->clientSecret)
);

$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency('EUR');
$amount->setTotal($order->getSum());

$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount);

$redirectUrls = new \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("http://localhost:8080/checkout/confirm");
$redirectUrls->setCancelUrl("http://localhost:8080/checkout/summary");

$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale')
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setTransactions(array($transaction))
    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);

try {
    $payment->create($apiContext);

    echo "\n\nRedirect user to approval_url: " . $payment->getApprovalLink() . "\n";
}
catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
    file_get_contents(CURRENT_PROJECT_DIRECTORY.'/tmp/paypal-log.log', $ex->getData());
}
```

Can someone give me some hints? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe an issue with the sandbox environment? I admit I've never actually double-checked any of my sandbox 'buyers' to see if funds actually changed in the test environ.

Comment: But how can I check that my payment is really working?

Comment: If the API returns without error (as you say, green checkmarked), you are to assume the API call is ok, and that paypal will uphold their promise if it was in production. Its what we did when integrating... tested all out API calls, and got tokens, and responses, and data. Since all the return data was AOK, we assumed it working, and switched to production environ... and things just worked from there (actual funds transferring around).

Comment: You can always write to PayPal Support and ask them to confirm your question. They would know best.